# How To use js variable into another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multiplication

I have a Javascript variable that has some value on-change. Now i want to use this variable in another file for some calculation.

For example i have my variable in index.php as follow:

```
    $(function() {
       $("#sel").on("change", function() {
       var vall = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value')
       alert(vall);
    });
   });
```

And in another file calculate.php i have code like this and want to use "vall" variable to multiple with "$total variable"

```
public function getGrandTotal(){
    $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $total = $quote->getGrandTotal();
    $gt =  $total *  var vall ; // "vall" variable to multiply with total

    return Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($gt);
}
```

Comment: Either submit a form or use ajax to send values to backend.

Comment: You can't access that, you can use form-submit or AJAX.

Comment: So how i can store that variable in ajax

Comment: `$.post('calculate.php', { val1 : val1 }, function(resp){ /* do something with the result */ })`

Answer (score 0):

That should be done with Ajax like:

```
$("#sel").on("change", function() {
   var vall = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({ 
       type:'post',
       url : "url to call",
       data:{val : vall}, // send vall here get as val in the backend.
       dataType:'text', // other values are json, script, html etc.
       success:function(data){
          console.log(data);  // <----get the response from the backend if echoed.
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: do you have time to check my issues through team viewer? @Jai